# geom_point does not always show up on map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I try to add points with custom coordinates to a map. In general, this seems to work with the NC map provided by the sf package. However, it does not work in a shapefile I downloaded from https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/open-data/verwaltungsgebiete-1-2-500-000-stand-31-12-vg2500-12-31.html - as long as I plot this new map only. If I plot both shapefiles at the same time, the points on the second shapefile suddenly appear. How would I add the custom points to the Germany-map only?

```
library("ggplot")    
library("sf")

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
ger_shape <- st_read("data/shapefiles/VG2500_LAN.shp")
ger_shape <- ger_shape[which(ger_shape$GF == 4),]

city <- data.frame(name = "1", lat = 35.7721, lng = -78.63861)
city2 <- data.frame(name = c("2","3"), lat = c(53,50), lng = c(10.2,10.2))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox") +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

[image: NC map with red point]

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ger_shape) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox") +
  geom_point(data = city2, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

[image: map without points]

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  geom_sf(data = ger_shape) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox") +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red') +
  geom_point(data = city2, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

[image: both maps with both sets of points]

Comment: I'm almost positive that the issue is the projection. You are giving lat long values to a shapefile that is likely in a projected coordinate system instead of a geographic coordinate system. What does `st_crs(ger_shape)` give you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the coordinate reference system (crs) used by the shapefiles for Germany provided by the BKG is Gauss-Kruger zone 3 (check `st_crs(ger_shape)`) which does not specify locations in degrees whereas you specified the city locations in degrees. As a result the coordinates for the cities are far away from Germany which you could see be dropping the `coord_sf` line:

```
library("ggplot2")    
library("sf")

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
ger_shape <- st_read("shp/VG250_LAN.shp")
ger_shape <- ger_shape[which(ger_shape$GF == 4),]

city2 <- data.frame(name = c("2","3"), lat = c(53,50), lng = c(10.2,10.2))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ger_shape) + 
  geom_point(data = city2, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

[image]

Hence, to add your points to the map of Germany you have to specify the coordinates in the crs of the shape file or transform the crs to e.g. `WGS84` using `st_transform` which specifies locations in degrees:

```
ger_shape <- sf::st_transform(ger_shape, "WGS84")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ger_shape) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox", crs = st_crs(ger_shape)) +
  geom_point(data = city2, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: Just a small remark: BKG data is not necessarily provided in GK3 only. The referenced [VG250](https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/open-data/verwaltungsgebiete-1-2-500-000-stand-31-12-vg2500-12-31.html) product for example is also offered in UTM32, EPSG: 25832. However, this nevertheless makes crs consolidation necessary - just as you described.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably just an issue with your coordinate system (projected instead of geographic). I am just guessing since I don't want to download the shapefile from the link provided. Here is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)    
library(sf)


nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
city <- data.frame(name = "1", lat = 35.7721, lng = -78.63861)

#projected, no point
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = st_transform(nc, crs = st_crs("EPSG:32616"))) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox") +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

[image]

```r
#geographic, point
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox") +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

[image]

Your problem will likely be fixed by setting the correct projection to use lat long coordinates:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = st_transform(ger_shape, crs = st_crs("NAD27"))) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox") +
  geom_point(data = city2, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

Comment: Your guess is right. The German shape files use Gauss-Kruger zone 3 as the crs. As a native German I'M used to this and had the shape file at hand. (:

Comment: Perfect. I felt pretty confident since almost all GIS-based "points not plotting on polygon" questions are coordinate system related. I'm glad you had the shapefile on hand. I'm eagerly waiting for a question about Illinois, USA to arise so that I might someday use (and justify) the many shapefiles I have on my computer.